# Horizontal scroll whitespace in the bottom of the RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am retrieving data from database using RadGrid.  I have more columns in my RadGrid, so I need to show RadGrid horizontal scroll to keep the page from expanding but disable the vertical scroll so height of the grid should expand to always display all rows in the grid.  I got the result but there is whitespace in the bottom of the RadGrid.

### My UI of the RadGrid:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"    border="0">

    <tr>

        <td>

            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true"

                CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Skin="Metro" CssClass="RadGrid_CBGrid"

                HorizontalAlign="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand"

                OnDataBound="RadGrid1_DataBound">

                <ClientSettings>

                    <Selecting CellSelectionMode="SingleCell"></Selecting>

                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>

                </ClientSettings>

                <MasterTableView HierarchyLoadMode="Client" DataKeyNames="EmpID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true"

                    Name="Parent">

                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

                    <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">

                    </RowIndicatorColumn>

                    <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">

                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>

                    <Columns>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmpID" EmptyDataText="NA" HeaderText="Emp ID"

                            UniqueName="EmpID">

                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                      and so on......
                      -------------------
                    </Columns>

                    <EditFormSettings>

                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">

                        </EditColumn>

                    </EditFormSettings>

                </MasterTableView>

                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">

                </FilterMenu>

            </telerik:RadGrid>

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

If I changed  ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="true" in RadGrid and

I got the result and there is NO whitespace in the bottom of the RadGrid BUT Horizontal scroll bar is NOT coming in my RadGrid.

So can anybody please give me the solution.

Comment: If you can link a photo of what whitespace you're talking about it might be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Use firebug in mozilla-firefox to get the reason why that white space is displaying at bottom. Is there any padding or margin there? Or if it is due to RadGrid's internal mechanism then you could hide it using overriding its css class.

Comment: Use Chrome, press F12 while on that web page with the grid. F12 will bring up the developer tools. In dev tools of Chrome, at the bottom left, click on magnifier then hover your mouse over the white are and click. Now in dev tools copy the highlighted html markup and paste it here for us to see.

Comment: I got the solution, thanks for all your suggestions. <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="True" ScrollHeight="" />

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to worry about hieght calculation do this!

```
// radgrid scroll horizontal only
<ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" AllowGroupExpandCollapse="true">                    
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" />
        <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
 </ClientSettings>

function GridCreated(sender, args) {
       $('.rgDataDiv').removeAttr('style');
       $('.rgDataDiv').attr('style', 'overflow-x: scroll;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change overflow-x property value of data grid to scroll , instead of applying auto. If you have this issue in IE9.