# How to enable grid horizontal scrolling with Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

Per title, I am trying to enable horizontal scrolling for a Telerik RadGrid. Beforehand, I used a parent div to control the width and height and then set the overflow property, which enabled horizontal scrolling. However, using this approach my grid stretches past the div width and along with it any uniformity.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
<div style="height:100%; float:left; width:99%">
    <div id="divFull" runat"server" style="width:99%; height:99%">
        <Telerik:RadGrid ID="deskFull" runat="server" Width="3200px" Height="100%"
            AllowPaging="True">
            <ClientSettings>
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True"
                    SaveScrollPosition="True" />
            </ClientSettings>
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" TableLayout="Fixed">
                <Columns>
                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Desk" HeaderText="Desk" />
                    <etc...>
                    <etc...>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </Telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am wanting to achieve is to not have the div tag control the scrolling, but rather the RadGrid itself. I have tried setting the column width to 200px via HeaderStyle-Width="200px" and restricting the grid's width to 100% of the parent div, but none of this worked. No horizontal scroll bar appeared on the grid and instead left a chunk of white space below the paging bar.

I have followed the online tutorials and have asked my colleague's for help, but no answers have come up.

Comment: have you tried adding ScrollHeight="" to the client settings?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589557/horizontal-scroll-whitespace-in-the-bottom-of-the-radgrid

Comment: @rogerdeuce Yes, I have tried setting the ScrollHeight but the parent div still controls the scrolling, not the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples of this on teleriks site

http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-horizontal-scrolling

which states:

*In order to display horizontal scroll for navigation, you need to make sure that the total width of the columns (either auto-generated or declaratively set) exceeds the width of the grid.*

and here is a live demo showing horizontal scrolling: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/scrolling/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx

Are you sure the width of all of the columns in your grid exceeds the grid width? Try setting the grid to a fixed width.

Comment: I looked at that tutorial before and there is nothing there that specifically helps this problem. I coded exactly what the demo has in its settings for the grid and nothing happened, just added white space. Like I said above, I set my grid to 100% width of my parent div, and then set each column to 200px each. The result was that 5 or 6 columns of 43 showed up, but there was no horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Have you tried giving the grid a fixed width instead of 100%?

Comment: I was setting the grid to 3200px and setting each column to exceed that width, but still nothing was happening. The solution, which does relate to your answer, was to set the column width IN the grid. I was setting the width on the back-end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My issue was the grid's min-width was set to 'fit-content.'  Once I removed that, the scrollbar showed up.